# Distance from a point in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to x-axis

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose I have a point $(a,b,c)$. What is the distance from this point to the $x$-axis?

I had supposed that it would be simply $\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$ but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: It is indeed $\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$. What made you think otherwise?

Comment: The answer system marks me wrong when I claim this.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a mistake elsewhere? The intuition behind this statement is that since $x$ coordinate does not affect the distance to $x$-axis, you can squash the whole space into the $x = 0$ plane and you already know how to find the distance there.

Comment: I had the very same intuition- turns out I added the $y^2$ and $z^2$ in question incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

In fact is $\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$. You can see this if you think about the  point $(a,b,c)$ in the plane $(a,0,0)$.